# Creating hibernate mappings- beginner qn

Tags: hibernate

I have the following tables, taken from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#db_schema_users_authorities) (as part of the Spring Security model):

```
  create table users(
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null primary key,
      password varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      enabled boolean not null);

  create table authorities (
      username varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      authority varchar_ignorecase(50) not null,
      constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username) references users(username));

  create unique index ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

I'm really new to hiberanate and am not sure how to map these tables to hibernate mappings in the xml file. How to map foreign keys? How to map indexes? I'm aware that every table has a primary key, but in this case, the authorities table doesn't. So that means that there is no `<id>` colum in the hibernate mappings?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<class name="com.foo.beans.User" table="users">
    <id name="username" column="username"/>
    <property name="password" column="password"/>
    <property name="enabled" column="enabled"/>
</class>

<class name="com.foo.beans.Authority" table="authorities">
    <composite-id name="ix_auth_username">
        <key-property name="username" column="username" />
        <key-property name="authority" column="authority" />
    </composite-id>
</class>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your bean structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend using Annotations instead of XML. XML is kind of old fashioned.

Using Annotations it would look like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_table")
public class User implements Serializable {

    Long userId;
    String username;
    String password;
    boolean enabled;

    @Id
    @Column(name="user_table_id")
    public Long getUserId() { return userId; }

    public void setUserId(Long id) { this.userId = userId; }

    @Column(name="username", length=80, nullable=true)
    public String getUsername() { return username };

    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; };
    /* getters and settings annotated et cetera */
}
```

Authority is likely to be a Lazy loaded list inside the user object.

So inside the user you would define something like:

```
List<Authority> authorities;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="userId",
               cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
               fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy("xyz")
public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities (List<Authority> authorities) { this.authorities = authorities; };
```

See the ref guide for more examples and annotation options:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/

Sebastian